# twitter bootstrap chzn-select is not working inside tabpanes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap chzn-select in my php project. The problem I am facing is chzn-select is working fine when i place outside the tab panes but not working when i use inside tab panes. 
 I have three tabs namely tab1 , tab 2, tab3.
the three tabs are inside a single form. 
    I wanted to use chzn-select using twitter bootstrap. It is working fine when i place outside the tab panes but not working when i use inside tab panes.

```
                        <!-- add employee form starts-->

                        <!-- morris stacked chart -->

          <div class="row-fluid">
                            <!-- block -->

            <div class="row-fluid section">
                         <!-- block -->
                 <div class="block">

                    <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                        <div class="muted pull-left">Add Employee</div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="block-content collapse in">
                           <div class="span12" id="content">

                             <div id="response_message"></div>    

                            <div id="rootwizard">
                              <div class="navbar">
                                <div class="navbar-inner">
                                   <div class="container">
                                    <ul>
                                     <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Step 3</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                      </div>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="add_employee_form" id="add_employee_form" method="post" action="add_employee_ajax.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator">

                    <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
                             <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        //  here it works fine  ....
                     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">

                   <fieldset>
          <div class="control-group" >
          <label class="control-label" for="emp_id">Employee Id</label>
         <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_id" name = "emp_id" type="text" placeholder="eg: hash027" value="" >
          <span id="live_val_empid"></span> <span id="val_emp_suggest"></span></div>
        </div>
// When i place here it does't works.. 
        <div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label" for="select01">Select list</label>


 <div class="controls">
   <select id="select01" class="chzn-select" >
      <option>something</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
         </select>
         </div>
         </div>
```

// code continues....